# Determine last iterate in a bash for loop

Tags: bash

I have a loop that adds some lines into a configuration file:

```
for i in ${H//,/ }
do
        sed -i "7i\                      host($i) or" $configPath/$g.conf
done
```

$H is a comma delimited variable, ex: host1,host2,host4,host10

It returns the following:

> ```
>                   host(host10) or
>                   host(host4) or
>                   host(host2) or
>                   host(host1) or
> ```

but what I want to achieve is:

> ```
>                   host(host10) or
>                   host(host4) or
>                   host(host2) or
>                   host(host1)
> ```

or vice versa:

> ```
>                   host(host1) or
>                   host(host2) or
>                   host(host4) or
>                   host(host10)
> ```

Who can help me putting me in the right direction, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: I guess you can have a if inside the loop like this `if [[ $i == ${H[-1]} ]]` to determine the last element of H.

Comment: Not if they are not unique?

Comment: I suspect this is a text processing question and not a shell question ? That is, you actually want to edit a config file right ? (in that case you don't want to use a `for` loop...)

Answer (score 6):

This problem arises in most programming languages in the same form. It's a complication to skip the suffix somehow. I won't go into shell syntax, but just outline in pseudo-code the ways people usually handle this:

```
# get it over with at the beginning:
print a[0] (no newline)
loop from a[1] onwards:
   print "or\n"
   print a[i]
print "\n" #terminate the last one
```

This case works either by looping over indices, or just looping over all elements (skipping the first one), as no index testing is involved (if the language supports direct iteration over arrays, such as bash and python do).

You could also start from 0 and skip the last one, and handle it outside the loop (the mirror image of the above), but skipping the last one is usually dirtier and may be impossible (to skip the last one, you must know it's the last one, but the first can always be skipped immediately). For instance, **if you are reading elements from the stream, you can't know ahead of time which one is the last, and this form is the only option**!

The othe way:

```
# test a loop counter
N = length of array
loop with indices:
   if i==N-1:
      print a[i]
   else:
      print a[i],"or"
```

Notice that this case needs you to know how many elements there are, and it constantly tests the index. For this reason, you must either loop over indices, or keep track of the index separately (setting i=0 before the loop and i++ inside).

I wrote this as a recipe, I'll leave the bash implementation to you.

Comment: It would be easier to loop on the N-1 first items and then to print the Nth item. That would save N tests.

Comment: Alternatively if you were to PREPEND the join string rather than APPENDING it, start with an empty join string and set it to "or /n" after the first iteration you will get the desired result without having to count the number of records or change the order.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see, you only need a slight change to your code: just put "or" in a variable that is empty during the first loop.

```
operator=''
for i in ${H//,/ }
do
        sed -i "7i\                      host($i)$operator" "$configPath/$g.conf"
        operator=' or'
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You generally don't want to use shell loops to do text processing. Here, I'd use `awk`:

```
export H
awk 'NR == 7 {
  s = ENVIRON["H"]
  gsub(/,/, ") or\n   host(", s)
  print "   host(" s ")"}
  {print}' file
```

Like GNU `sed` has that `-i` option for in-place editing, GNU `awk` (since 4.1.0) has `-i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk`¹ as an equivalent.

If you want to edit a text file, one could argue that you should use a text editor. With `vim`, you could implement the same approach with:

```
export H
vim -esc '
  let @a=$H
  6put a
  s/.*/host(&)/
  s/,/) or\rhost(/g
  x' file
```

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>

Comment: Possible beartrap: gawk's `-i` is actually "include file", and `inplace.awk` is a library script which emulates this behaviour (via `BEGINFILE`/`ENDFILE`), it requires the `inplace` extension module to be available (≥ v4.1.0)

Comment: @mr.spuratic, thanks. I've added a note about the minimum required version.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to orion's answer with the explanation and pseudo-code I could come up with following BaSH script, used for Zabbix ElasticSearch-index discovery, which gets all indices from ElasticSearch and prints a valid JSON object: (for the JSON object to validate I need the last element without a comma `,` so I put all elements in an array, skip the first iteration and handle it as last one outside the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Zabbix-Agent discovery for ElasticSearch indices
# UserParameter=es.indices.discovery,/etc/zabbix/es-indices-discovery.sh
indices=($(echo $(curl -n --silent -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=index | egrep -v "^\.")))

echo -e "{"
echo -e "\t\"data\":["
for i in "${!indices[@]}"; do
    if [ $i == 0 ]; then continue; fi
    echo -en "\t\t{"
    echo -en "\t\"{#INDEXNAME}\":\"${indices[$i]}\""
    echo -e "\t\t},"
done
echo -en "\t\t{"
echo -en "\t\"{#INDEXNAME}\":\"${indices[0]}\""
echo -e "\t\t}"

echo -e "\t]"
echo "}"
```

output:

```
{
        "data":[
                {       "{#INDEXNAME}":"index2"         },
                {       "{#INDEXNAME}":"index3"         },
                {       "{#INDEXNAME}":"index4"         },
                {       "{#INDEXNAME}":"firstindex"             }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the "sed" in the original question, I have written a simpler one with echo to illustrate the idea: Instead of looping through the whitespace separated items:

- First we get the word count after "," substitution to determine the number of iterations
- Convert the whitespaced string to an array with "()"
- Iterate through counts
- Make " or" part an output of a conditional and into a variable
- Subset the array with iteration
- And echo/sed, etc

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  H="host1,host2,host3"
  H2=${H//,/ }
  N=`echo $H2 | wc -w`
  H3=($H2)

  for ((i = 1; i <= $N; i++))
  do
      if [ "$i" -eq "$N" ]; then OR=""; else OR=" or"; fi
      ITEM=${H3[$i-1]}
      echo "$ITEM$OR"
  done
  ```

Comment: You don't need `wc` to compute `N` just use `${#H3[*]}`

Answer (score 0):

I think ADV-IT solution in fact works (I don't have enough reputation in order to comment his answer, that's why I am replying to the original question).

Consider the following adapted code:

```
H="172.11.61.27,172.31.22.131,172.31.32.221"
FORMATTED_OUTPUT=""
JOINT=""
for ip in ${H//,/ }
do
    FORMATTED_IP="                      host($ip)"
    FORMATTED_OUTPUT=$FORMATTED_OUTPUT$JOINT$FORMATTED_IP
    JOINT=" or"$'\n'
done

echo "${FORMATTED_OUTPUT}"
```

Essentially, his idea is to **prepend**, for each entry, a prefix. In his original answer, this prefix was (except for the first entry) the comma (in his code the variable `COLUMN` corresponds to this prefix).

In my code I adapted everything in order to reply the original question. The idea is the same: for all entries, except for the first one, you prepend a preffix (in my case, I named it `JOINT`, which takes the value of `or` string. If you draw/write/imagine this, effectively will achieve the intended output. Notice I had to add also a newline in order to format the output.

I think it's an alternative way to solve the problem: instead of appending a suffix (except for the last line), you prepend a prefix (except for the first line). Nice!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the prefix:

```
H="host1,host2,host4,host10"
for i in ${H//,/ }; do
        printf "$prefix%18shost(host$i)"
        prefix=" or\n"
done
printf "\n"
```

Comment: (1) This is essentially the same as the three previous answers ([xhienne’s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384848/80216), [ADV-IT’s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/534821/80216) and [jquinter’s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/554616/80216)) except for cosmetic differences. (2) Well, more than cosmetic.  Your ```printf``` command is missing some quotes.

Comment: The answer does not provide any extra info already in the previous answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
    LIST="172.11.61.27 172.31.22.131 172.31.32.221"
    ES_LIST=""
    COLUMN=""
    for ip in $LIST;
    do
          ES_IP="\"$ip\""
          ES_LIST=$ES_LIST$COLUMN$ES_IP
          COLUMN=","
    done


   echo $ES_LIST
```

`"172.11.61.27", "172.31.22.131","172.31.32.221"`

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer, please?